# How to open compressed file in less mode

Tags: ksh, aix, less, compression

How do I open a compressed file in `less` mode. I am able to `grep` using `zgrep` and using `zcat`I can open, but the file is big I want to open in `less` mode.

Comment: You didn't specify the type of compression - `zgrep` for example doesn't work with `zstd` compress (ok that one wasn't around when you wrote the question). So this quesiton is only valid for `gzip` style compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what pipes were made for:

```
 gzip -dc | less
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `zless` utility from that same gzip suite, it combines functionality of `gzip -d` and `less` into one